# Jenkins Artifactory Release Plugin Unable To Commit Tag (Windows Host Machine)

Tags: git, jenkins, artifactory

Jenkins is running on a Windows server 2012 host.

The build runs successfully up until the point where the release should be tagged.

Build log:

```
C:\build_tools\Git\cmd\git.exe config --get remote.origin.url # timeout=10
C:\build_tools\Git\cmd\git.exe add -u # timeout=10
C:\build_tools\Git\cmd\git.exe commit -F C:\Windows\TEMP\gitcommit4513460760895217486.txt # timeout=10
Failure in post build SCM action: Cannot commit [artifactory-release] Release version 2.1.1
```

when manually running the above steps via the command line, it appears the issue is that git commit does not properly handle the pound sign (# timeout=10), resulting in the error:

> error: pathspec '#' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: What is the "# timeout=10" for? If it is just a comment, on the command line you should use REM. I have not seen this syntax before, so my comment may be pointless

Comment: The lines posted in the question are all generated by the plugins (I think the Artifactory plugin, but I am not clear as to where it leaves off and the git plugin picks up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of this error turns out to be that I had failed to set the "Global Config user.name" property for the Git Plugin.

Comment: We had the same problem.  We were using git credentials override, but it appears that that Jenkins feature does not work.  We had to set the global configured version control system username in order to get the commit to work, and it committed under the globally-configured name, not the overridden name.